# jQuery hiding only a part of a <tr> in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a table that will be dynamically filled the structure is like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> The </td><td> Fields </td><td> To </td><td>Be</td><td>visible</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

and the same structure 2 times but it has to be hidable on load and and click and to show when clicked

```
</tr>
... the other trs ...

<table>
```

I want the second and third `tds` to slide down and up when I click the first `td`.

Comment: Second and third `<td>` in one row to slide down/up? Are you sure it is possible?

Comment: Nah my mistake sorry about that. I saw what I wrote but ... there have to be like 3 trs.. (I will edit it) and when the first one is clicked to close/hide the other three

Comment: the first tr toggles the second and third, thease are used for a reccord of a users showing basic info on the first row and second and third will hold additional info

Comment: I have edited the code below, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table > tr > td').first().bind('click', function (event) {
    $(this).next().slideToggle().next().slideToggle();
});
```

Update:
Go with the following: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2QaUX/6/)

```
<table>
    <thead><!-- Clickable Header --></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><!-- Content --></tr>
    <tr><!-- Content --></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table tbody').css('display', 'none');
    $('table thead').click(function (event) {
        $('table tbody').slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Works under IE9/FF/Webkit for me. Are you using a different browser?

Comment: Opera =D can you give me suggestion that includes opera ?

Comment: I don't even have opera installed :S Debug it through dragonfly, maybe the selector needs to be tweaked. See if the length of the selector is 0.

Comment: It doesnt work on chrome, and IE8, and as well as opera.. I am testing it on jsfiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16023/discussion-between-d-dimitrov-and-konstantin-dinev)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this
```

***HTML***

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="clickitem">
            The
        </td>
        <td>
            Fields
        </td>
        <td>
            To
        </td>
        <td>
            Be
        </td>
        <td>
            visible
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$('.clickitem').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qYJ3B/9/